# iPhone ignoring all media queries

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries

The website was working absolutely fine a few months back. Suddenly no iPhone is reading a single media query within the css file. I have done the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Included in my html file.

```
/* Iphone 6 plus portrait & landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) {
```

Included in my CSS file

Tried the following:

```
@media all and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) {

and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 

and (min-resolution: 401dpi) 
and (device-aspect-ratio:16/9)
```

Nothing.

I checked that the CSS file is loading.

When I check the site via Chrome, on my Windows PC, in the iPhone 6+ resolution it looks perfect. But the client, as well as every single iPhone simulator I have tried, is showing none of the media queries. I do not actually have an iPhone, but the client does.

Can anyone please explain how this could be happening? What am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the solution was to add (max-width) / (min-width) alongside every max-device-width and min-device-width. This made the query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) 
 and (max-device-width : 736px) 
 and (orientation : portrait), 
 only screen and (min-width: 414px) 
 and (max-width : 736px) and (orientation : portrait) { }
```

This is working on the simulator, will test further and add more if required.